# Number of trie nodes required to represent certain number of strings

Tags: string, trie

I am supposed to implement Trie data structure to represent a dictionary. There are 1000 words ( lowercase letters ) in the dictionary and each of them has a length ranging from 1 to 10. I am not allowed to dynamically allocate the memory which means I have to declare required number of Trie nodes before-hand. It will be of great help if any body can suggest any formulation regarding required number of nodes for 1000 words in the worst case scenario ?  ( 1000 * 10 is not an answer it can be minimized )

I am able to calculate for few words say 10 or 20 but I am not able to formalize them.

Comment: Please show some attempt to solve the problem. If you know how to do it with dynamic allocation this could be a starting point.

Comment: The quickest solution would be to just build a dynamically allocated trie and count the number of nodes.

Comment: I know how to dynamically allot, but I am not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute worst case is a trie where all words are the maximum size and you prevent sharing prefixes as much as possible.

Assuming lowercase a-z letters, all words can be of the following shape:

```
[a-z][a-z][a-z]aaaaaaa
```

with the [a-z] parts unique for each word. We need a three-letter prefix because `26^2 < 1000 < 26^3`

We then have the following trie layout:

- At the first level, all 26 nodes are filled (= 26 nodes)
- At the second level, each first-level node has 26 children (= 676 nodes)
- At the third level, 1000 nodes will exist, as we have 1000 words (= 1000 nodes)
- Each of these 1000 nodes will have a string of 7 'a' nodes below it ( = 7000 nodes)

This results in a total of 26 + 676 + 1000 + 7000 = 8702 nodes.